# "System" process high cpu usage

Tags: windows-7, drivers, cpu-usage

I've been noticing the cpu usage go up, back down for a couple minutes, and then go up again, and vice-versa...

Not constant but it happened several times. (almost always up to 23% cpu constant when it happens)

This happened just now only with firefox interaction, got skype and LoLClient running too..

Looking at it in Process Explorer, i see two files taking approximately 10% each:

ntoskrnl.exe
dxgmms1.sys

The problem is after looking up that dxmgmms1.sys i found that it stands for "Microsoft DirectX Graphics MMS system driver file." and i can't remember updating it at all.
The other one i believe it's what's enabling or something since it's kinda part of the Windows kernel?

I've done sfc couple months ago when i first noticed this, runned malware scans, windows always up-to-date and everything.

How can i fix this?

Edit: It happened again, i done a xperf scan as suggested:

> xperf -on latency -stackwalk profile -buffersize 1024 -MaxFile 512
>   -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d highCPUUsage.etl

I uploaded the file to my dropbox, can someone tell analyze it or something? Or should i post on the msdn forums?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36066558/highCPUUsage.7z

Thanks to whoever helps, hope i recorded it correctly, it displayed [a warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPZZL.png) when i started the trace.

Comment: Why do you think something's broken?

Comment: capture and share a xperf trace: http://forum.sysinternals.com/need-help-with-ntoskrnl-thread-causing-high-cpu_topic29289.html

Comment: @kreemoweet Because 23% constant in an out on random occasions i believe it's broken.
It bothers me mostly because this is a laptop, although it's an i7, this happened to me while playing too one time and i simply couldn't play with such lag. It happens quite frequently, and i can't see a reason why.

Comment: @magicandre1981 When it happens again, i'll do that, thanks.

Comment: did it happen again?

Comment: Actually, it did couple days ago, but i wasn't in time to do the test, same 22/23% though, i'll be prompting to do it next time.

Comment: the link expired. Next time, notify me with the @ my username that you added a link.

Comment: was the issue ever fixed?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry, dk why just got notified about your comment today... anyway, it was the intel graphics driver for my HD5400 that was causing the problem, i could confirm because i had two graphics and whenever i opened a livecoding.tv stream on firefox using the intel card, the SYSTEM cpu would spyke, running firefox with the nvidia card both the SYSTEM cpu and the firefox cpu would be lower (SYSTEM was unchanged but firefox reduced from 12-13 to like 3-5% for the stream alone.

Idk if they ever fixed that, i just stopped running the intel card on every application that caused that.

Comment: Since the nvidia card was extremely better anyway.

Comment: ok, post this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Following @magicandre1981 advice, i'll post my "solution".

The culprit was the driver for my Intel HD5400 card, i noticed every time i opened a stream on livecoding.tv (can't remember if it had the same problem on twitch for example) my CPU would spyke to 30-35%, upon closer look, i saw firefox was eating 12-15% and SYSTEM process was eating another 15% just for the stream alone.

Since it was a laptop and it had two cards on Sandy Bridge, i began to ran firefox and basically every other program as the nvidia card (gt650m) since it was better anyway, in this case the SYSTEM cpu stayed at ~0% and firefox cpu stayed at 3-5%, which was a 25% cpu overall reduction.

I don't know if the driver ever got fixed, i just use the nvidia card.